# Python pandas read_csv dtype object empty csv

Tags: python, csv, pandas

I want to read some CSV files from a folder and I don't know the contents of the CSV files. Some CSV has no data rows but all has the same header row. I want to read these CSV files into a dataframe in which all coloumns' datatype is `object`. How can I do this in one line? This throws an exception at empty CSV-s (in Python 2.7.10, pandas 0.17.1):

```
df = pd.read_csv('my.csv', dtype=object)

AttributeError: type object 'object' has no attribute 'items'
```

At empty CSV files I get `object` datatypes if I delete the `dtype=object` parameter. It's funny... If the CSV has minimum one data row, the above code works perfectly.

Comment: Try passing `dtype=np.object`

Comment: is it possible the files are invalid? presumably you have `import numpy as np` prior to my suggestion?

Comment: Yes, I use `import numpy as np`, and I get NO errors if I use only this code: `df = pd.read_csv('my.csv')`. So the file is valid, I can print out the `df` or the data types of it.

Comment: have you shadowed the `object` keyword perhaps?